# Moduli spaces of stable sheaves on noncommutative projective schemes

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, noncommutative-algebra, noncommutative-geometry

In noncommutative algebraic geometry in the sense of Artin and Zhang, can we construct moduli spaces of stable sheaves on noncommutative projective schemes as (commutative)schemes ?

I would appreciate it if you could tell me any previous research on this question.
Of course, other comments are welcome!

Comment: See, for example, Section 2 in M. Finkelberg, V. Ginzburg, A. Ionov, A. Kuznetsov "Intersection cohomology of the Uhlenbeck compactification of the Calogero-Moser space", Selecta Math., V. 22 (2016), N. 4, pp. 2491-2534

Comment: Thank you very much !

Comment: In the above paper, the authors construct moduli spaces of sheaves on noncommutative projective plane. Is it difficult to construct moduli spaces of sheaves on other noncommutative surfaces ?